# Error after updating to Angular 4.1.3(Webpack 2)

Tags: angular, webpack, dependencies, migration

I am working on updating quite a hefty project, that is way past due on its update schedule.

After updating to angular 4.1.3, I am getting this error:

error TS2314: Generic type 'Type' requires 1 type argument(s).

Here is the code: `

```
import {Type} from "@angular/core";
import {ModalComponent} from "./modal/components/modal";
import {ModalHeaderComponent} from "./modal/components/modal-header";
import {ModalBodyComponent} from "./modal/components/modal-body";
import {ModalFooterComponent} from "./modal/components/modal-footer";

export * from './modal/components/modal';
export * from './modal/components/modal-header';
export * from './modal/components/modal-body';
export * from './modal/components/modal-footer';

export const MODAL_DIRECTIVES: Type[] = [
ModalComponent,
ModalHeaderComponent,
ModalBodyComponent,
ModalFooterComponent
];
```

`

Line 12 is the one causing the error. How do I have to rework this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be Type any.

```
 export const MODAL_DIRECTIVES: Type<any>[] = [
    AppComponent,
    SuggesterComponent,
    AssetResultsComponent,
    AssetComponent,
    MillisTohhMmSs,
 ]
```

**Edit**

did u tried like this. otherwise you can try like

if its not working you can directly add you components in to ngmodule example

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
 AppComponent,
        SuggesterComponent,
        AssetResultsComponent,
        AssetComponent,
        MillisTohhMmSs,
]
```

Comment: It will not allow me to cast it as <any>